# QMessageBox position on QMessageBox.warning call

Tags: python, macos, pyqt

From current window I am trying to create a simple confirmation dialog using QMessageBox.

My code is:

```
res = QMessageBox.question(QMessageBox(currentWindow), "Question",  "Are you sure?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
```

The problem is that the confirmation dialog appears in absolutely random place on the screen and not on top of the parent window. I observe this behavior on MacOS 10.12. And it is also the case for QMessageBox.warning, QMessageBox.critical, and other static methods.

Is there any way to set the position of modal dialog to be relative to its parent?

Comment: use `res = QMessageBox.question(currentWindow, "Question",  "Are you sure?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
`

Comment: eyllanesc, I tried, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `QMessageBox::question()` is the parent which will be used by the dialog box. A `QDialog` is centered (and modal) on its parent.

By doing `QMessageBox.question(QMessageBox(currentWindow)`, you pass a new instance of `QMessageBox` which is not displayed.

Pass `currentWindow` instead:

```
res = QMessageBox.question(currentWindow, "Question", "Are you sure?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
```

But, you need to be sure that `currentWindow` is displayed and not `None`.